# Cannot find variable - Variable "form" does not exist in...

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am trying to create a simple form within Symfony. Not quite sure why this is not grabbing the form variable.

Receiving error:

*Variable "form" does not exist src/Thinkfasttoys/MapWatchBundle/Resources/views/Default/createMapPolicy.html.twig at line 30*

**Controller - DefaultController.php**

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
public function policyFormAction()
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('age', 'integer')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
        ;

    return $this->render('ThinkfasttoysMapWatchBundle:Default:createMapPolicy.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
}
```

**View - createMapPolicy.html.twig**

```
{% block body %}
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="widget-box">
                        <h4 align="center", padding="10px 0 10px 0">Create a New MAP Policy</h4>

                        {{ form(form) }}

                        <div class="container-1">

                        </div><!-- /.container -->    
                    </div><!-- /.widgetbox -->
                </div>
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what symfony version are you using?

Comment: I notice in your render you specify: `ThinkfasttoysMapWatchBundle:Default:createMapPolicy.html.twig` but in your error it shows: `src/Thinkfasttoys/MapWatchBundle/Resources/views/Default/createMapPolicy.html.twig`  Is it possible you have two different files?

Comment: I am using version 2.7

Answer (score 1):

In twig you have to display the form like this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: tried this previously - produces same variable "form" does not exist error

Comment: where are you mapping your route?

Comment: Actually, form(form) will work just fine.  Your question about route mapping is a good one.  It is possible that a different action is calling the template though it seems unlikely.